# TaskStackBuilder on older version Android

Tags: android, notifications

I need to show a `Notification` on Android `GingerBread` but `TaskStackBuilder` which I use is used from Android version 3 and up.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.red)
            .setContentTitle("Notification.")
            .setContentText(incomingNumber);

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

notification.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
```

How can I do this on Android < v3.0?

Answer (score 0):

TaskStackBuilder works fine on Android < 3.0, you just need to use the version from the support library.